# Как загрузить изображение из интернета в InfoWindowAdapter Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

При нажатии на маркер пытаюсь загрузить изображение и получить окошко с ним, но View v возвращается прежде, чем загрузится картинка.Как дождаться выполнения AsyncTask не блокируя основной поток?Возможно ли это вообще, и имеются какие нибудь альтернативные решения? Заранее спасибо.

```
public class MarkerInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_window, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        GetImage getImage = new GetImage();
        getImage.execute();
        return v;
    }

    class GetImage extends AsyncTask<Void, View, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return downloadImage(chosenMarker.getUrl());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можно, наверное, вернуть невидимый view, а потом в `onPostExecute` его показать

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Его надо каким то образом обновить в onPostExecute ,не знаете ,как это сделать?Если просто показать, то он будет пустой.

Comment: А, проблема в том, что не гарантируют обновление окна при обновлении элементов. В [ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15512984) на enSO советуют запоминать маркер, и после загрузки и установки картинки вызывать у него `.showInfoWindow()`.

Comment: Да спасибо, это сработало)

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) для загрузки изображений.

```
    public class MarkerInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_window, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load(chosenMarker.getUrl()).into(imageView);
        return v;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask довольно плохое решение для этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

**Info Window** не является обычным виджетом. В [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) написано:

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().

Т.е. виджет просто рисуется поверх карты. Чтобы обновить окно, нужно вызвать `showInfoWindow()`.

Для этого [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512984) в `getInfoContents` сохранять ссылку на `Marker`, и после загрузки картинки вызывать `marker.showInfoWindow()`, если окно еще отображается.

С помощью Picasso так можно сделать, передав в `into(ImageView target, Callback callback)` [свою реализацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690182) `Callback`.